# how to get multiple N input in one line

Tags: ruby

how to get input of N multiple integer in one line like this below?

```ruby
2  # -> is integer, maximum integer can be input
1 1 # -> is each integer. you can't input more than maximum (which is 2)
```

i try

```ruby
max = gets.to_i
puts gets.chomp.split.map(&:to_i)
```

but the second line does not stop me to input number based on max. it will be stop until i enter

Comment: Given `max` do you wish to extract the first `max` integer representations in the string? For example, if `max = 2` and the string were `"a 12 b3 c 56 c 78"` would you wish to extract `'12'` and `'3'`?

Comment: let say `max = 2`. then i enter right. then i input again, let say `1` and i press space and i input `1`  again then it will be automatically end the input / puts `1 1`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create an error when more than the max number of inputs are entered, this could be quite simple using `#take`.

```
max = gets.to_i
all_numbers = gets.chomp.split.map(&:to_i)
max_numbers = all_numbers.take(max)

p max_numbers
```

Comment: it also works, but it will not stop input on second input. what i want is if the inputted number count is max count the just print them, no more input again